# Symfony2 with Twig and RequireJs

Tags: jquery, symfony, requirejs, twig

I want to create my frontend javascript logic using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), but also want to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for modules load on demand. I'm using the Symfony2 and Twig templates.

The question is:

If I load a main page of the site, the RequireJS kicks in and loads everything that is needed for this frontpage. But now if I click on a menu link, the new route is selected and the new template is rendered. In this case will I need a new `require.config()` for this new route of the page? What would be the right way of loading the necessary modules for new route?

P.S. This would not be a SPA, I will fetch some JSON data from backend with AJAX, but most job will be done by a backend rendering templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar task to resolve so my solution was follwonig :

1) Single require config file: Keeps paths, shims common deps.

2) On page load / reload: i've used iniline script on the bottom of the page with required modules set for the page.

```
<script>
    // some_page
    require(['mod1', 'mod2'], function() {
        // do something
    });
</script>
// other_page
<script>
    // other_page
    require(['mod3', 'mod4'], function() {
        // do something else
    });
</script>
```

3) On production i've used minified file with all modules in it. You may be interested in building separate bundles for each page in case you don't have many common deps on majority of your page. For more info checkout [RequireJS bundles docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles)